# Does angular 16 does not support ng search filter?

Tags: angular, angular-material

does angular 16 does not support ng search filter ? As I'm getting error after implementing it as "the library (ng2-search-filter) which declares Ng2SearchPipeModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy"

Please Help. I need to implement search functionality without using pipes.

Comment: It was already archived by maintainer you can check https://github.com/solodynamo/ng2-search-filter/blob/master/src/ng2-filter.pipe.ts source code and create your own pipe.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "without using pipes"? The linked library hasn't been updated in 4 years and is [written](https://github.com/solodynamo/ng2-search-filter/blob/e8727f3e1e47ff44f7e0e0a9b923fe3d268937dd/package.json#L29) with Angular v2. In essence, it's a [single straight-forward pipe](https://github.com/solodynamo/ng2-search-filter/blob/e8727f3e1e47ff44f7e0e0a9b923fe3d268937dd/src/ng2-filter.pipe.ts). I don't see an issue porting it into your project.

Comment: I just wanted to know that can't we use ng search filter in angular 16 ?

Comment: like this "filter : searchText" in html

Answer (score 0):

Yes as of now it does not support .

you can try out -> https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app/first-app-lesson-13